Excel-DNA function - Turn off default trigger by VBA Application.Calculate
I have a Excel-DNA function which feeds into a range of cells on the worksheet. The function is triggered everytime I call Application.Calculate in the VBA code but I only want it triggered by Application.Calculate in certain circumstances. Is there any way to control this?
[ExcelFunction(Description = "Returns data 2D matrix to Excel sheet")]
public static object GetDataIntoCells(String sheet)
{
    return GetData(sheet);
}


"certain circumstances" could be a bit more specific?

I want to refresh that range seperately and on-demand, for performance reasons. The spreadsheet is large and complicated - I DO want to use Application.Calculate to caculate the rest of it, but not trigger that Excel-DNA function as part of Application.Calculate.

I've never used Excel-DNA but could you cache the result from GetData(sheet) and just return the cached version when called, unless some other process has cleared the cache (in which case recalculate the result) ?

Thanks @TimWilliams. It's a good suggestion but in this case only makes a marginal difference. With caching, the C# function takes about 1 ms to run (down from ~13ms) however on the Excel side it still takes ~100ms to load the data onto the sheet, regardless of whether the function is returning the cached data or not (it returns about 5000 rows x 100 cols) so I was hoping for a way to avoid it being called at all.

Does something like Application.Evaluate("GetData(""sheetName"")") work with your function?
